# Predicting occurance of an event using time series data

Tags: machine-learning

I have data coming from sensors for 1 month. The data is time series with each data point separated by interval of 1 second. There are predictors like temperature, pressure, speed of the fan that has been recorded by these sensors.
Basis these values the event is recorded. So if the engine is functioning normally then event=0 else the event=1 and this event continues for considerable amount of time say next 10 mins and again gets back to normal.

I am trying to predict the occurrence of the next event basis the values of the predictors. I tried Cox proportional hazard model, however the survival curves are not accurate. Tried random forest too, however the model results were not great. The model accuracy was always at 100%.

Can survival analysis be used on time series data?
Would Clustering help?

Answer (score 0):

"I am trying to predict the occurrence of the next event basis the values of the predictors". Well, it seems that clustering is not what you want. Search for Linear Regression or Time Series Regression Methods. A simple introduction here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/intro.html and a more academic material here: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/hhsurveys/finalpublication/ch19fin3.pdf. Hope it helps.